# Return part of string in array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

So I'm trying to make this little script work for fun and just cant get it to work, 
I have an array of random names that are assigned their 'random' email addresses, I want to check if the email address have extension:
 '@hotmail.com',
 '@hotmail.ca', or
 '@yahoo.ca' . if they are then echo something like 'Daniel, your email addresses extension is $extension, you qualify'
and if they don't just say 'Kayla, your email address is $extension, you don't qualify.

I want to add a foreach statement explaining that for each person in the array $ClassRoom2, i've tried using strstr() but it doesn't work inside the foreach because it can only have one string.

heres what i got so far:

```
qualify = "";       
 $ClassRoom2 =  array(
            'Daniel' => 'fresco@hotmail.com',
            'Mike' => 'dkoko@yahoo.ca',
            'Meranda' => 'brunnn_23@hotmail.ca',
            'Will' => 'yumyum03@wp.pl',
            'Brittey' => 's0sd@outlook.com',
            'Kayla' => 'hocklife@freebie.com' );


    switch ($ClassRoom2) {
        case '@hotmail.com': 
            echo 'You are using extension '. $final; $qualify = 1; break;

        case '@hotmail.ca':
            echo 'You are using extension '. $final; $qualify = 1; break;

        case '@yahoo.com':
            echo 'You are using extension '. $final; $quality = 1; break;

        case '@yahoo.ca':
            echo 'You are using extension '. $final; $qualify = 1; break;

        case '@live.ca':
            echo 'You are using extension '. $final; $quality = 1; break;

        default:
            echo 'its something else'; $qualify = 0;
            break;
    }


    if ($qualify == 1) {
        echo "Congratulations, you quality for the contest. The extension you chose was <b>$final</b>";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry mate! you didn't quality for the contest.";
    }
```

Comment: use `explode('@','email@blabla.com')`..

Comment: `strrpos('fresco@hotmail.com', '@hotmail.com', 0) === 0`

Comment: You might want to use a [loop](http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php) and a [regular expression](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php), e.g. `@hotmail\.[a-z]{2,3}`. Have a look at [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and [' preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for my late reaction, I was still testing my code example.

If you want to stick with the switch you currently designed, you could use a simple [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to extract the string you need. Here is a little example (you can remove the comment and put in your switch there):

```
<?php
$ClassRoom2 =  array(   
    'Daniel' => 'fresco@hotmail.com',
    'Mike' => 'dkoko@yahoo.ca',
    'Meranda' => 'brunnn_23@hotmail.ca',
    'Will' => 'yumyum03@wp.pl',
    'Brittey' => 's0sd@outlook.com',
    'Kayla' => 'hocklife@freebie.com' 
);

foreach ($ClassRoom2 as $name=>$email) {
    $matches = [];
    preg_match( "/(@.+)/", $email, $matches);

    // Do things with $matches[0] here (your switch for eg)
    // switch ($matches[0]) {
    //    case '@hotmail.com': 
    //    ...

    print '<br/> ' . $matches[0];
}
?>
```

If you want, you can fiddle arround with preg matches on this website: [regexr](http://regexr.com/)

**Update** You can actually do a lot with `preg_match`, once you get the hang of it :)

```
foreach ($ClassRoom2 as $name=>$email) {
    $matches = preg_match( "/@(hotmail.com|hotmail.ca|yahoo.ca|yahoo.com|live.ca)/", $email);
    // if ($matches) // or simply replace the preg_match in the if
    print '<br/> ' . $email . ($matches ? ' qualifies' : ' <strong>does not qualify</strong> ') .  'for the email test';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use explode() to get the domain part and compare it

```
$parts = explode("@", "johndoe@domain.com");
echo ($parts[1]=='domain.com') ? 'qualify' : 'not qualify';
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put the list of entries and the qualifying extensions on separate arrays then check each people entry and parse their information to see if each qualify, like this:

```
$peoplelist =  array(
    'Daniel' => 'fresco@hotmail.com',
    'Mike' => 'dkoko@yahoo.ca',
    'Meranda' => 'brunnn_23@hotmail.ca',
    'Will' => 'yumyum03@wp.pl',
    'Brittey' => 's0sd@outlook.com',
    'Kayla' => 'hocklife@freebie.com' 
);

$qualify = array(
    'hotmail.com', 
    'hotmail.ca', 
    'yahoo.com', 
    'yahoo.ca', 
    'live.ca', 
);

foreach( $peoplelist as $name => $email )
{
    $parts = explode( "@", $email ); 
    $extension = strtolower( trim( array_pop( $parts ) ) );

    echo "Hi, ".$name.". You are using extension @".$extension.". <br /> \n";

    if( in_array( $extension, $qualify ) )
    {
        echo "Congratulations, you quality for the contest. <br /> \n";
    }
}
```